# System Stack Error

Tags: ruby

So I have the following code for a Merge Sort in Ruby.

```
class MergeSort

     def sort(array)
               if array.length == 1 || array.length == 0
                   return array
               end
               firstHalf = array[0..array.length / 2]
               secondHalf = array[(array.length / 2) + 1..array.length]
               firstHalf = sort(firstHalf)
               secondHalf = sort(secondHalf)
               b = 0
               c = 0
               for i in (0..(firstHalf.length - 1))
                  while b < secondHalf.length && firstHalf[i] >= secondHalf[b]
                       array[c] = secondHalf[b]
                       b = b + 1
                       c = c + 1
                  array[c] = firstHalf[i]
                  c = c + 1
               end
               return array
     end

end

array = [1,4,9,14,20,25]
puts MergeSort::new.sort(array)
```

When I run the code, I get a `SystemStackError`. Can someone tell me why this is happening? Thanks.

Comment: It does not raise a SystemStackError. It raises a syntax error.

Answer (score 1):

At a guess, once the array length gets to 3 (i.e. elements `[0..2]`), the call

```
firstHalf = array[0..array.length / 2]
```

evaluates to

`0..1.5` and if 1.5 is rounded up to 2

which then calls sort `[0..2]` again

and eventually you get a stack overflow?

Answer (score 0):

In order to call `.new` you have to have an `initialize` method in your class.
What you probably wanted to do was calling `.sort` on the class itself, in which case you have to prefix it with `self`, so:

```
class MergeSort
   def self.sort(array)
   ...
```

Afterwards you can call it like this:

```
MergeSort.sort(array)
```